# Detect resigning frontmost app with UIKit on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, ipad, uikit, mac-catalyst

I have an iPad app that receives chat messages through a web socket. If the app is in the foreground when this happens, the message is marked as read since the user is likely to have read it.

When running the app on macOS it is always foreground and active. The `willResignActiveNotification` and `didEnterBackgroundNotification` notifications are only sent if the app is minimized. This means that at present a message received when the app is covered by another app, will be marked as read even if the use can't have seen it.

**How can to tell if the app is not the frontmost app?**

I see that AppKit has a concept of a `frontmostApplication`, but there doesn't seem to be any equivelent in UIKit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UIKit, there is no direct API to determine if your app is the frontmost app on macOS. The concept of frontmost application is not exposed through public APIs in UIKit for iOS or macOS. One approach you can consider is to observe the NSWorkspaceDidActivateApplicationNotification notification from the NSWorkspace class provided by AppKit. Although it is AppKit-specific, you can still use it in your macOS app alongside UIKit.

Comment: Can you point me to documentation for how to use an AppKit API in a UIKit app?

Comment: I found this post helpful in getting things set up. 

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667569

Comment: There is no official documentation for how to use an AppKit API in a UIKit app, but there are some online resources that might help you. One approach is to use SwiftUI as a bridge between UIKit and AppKit, by wrapping your UIKit or AppKit views in a SwiftUI view that conforms to the UIViewRepresentable or NSViewRepresentable protocols1. Another approach is to use Mac Catalyst to port your UIKit app to macOS, and then use the @available(macCatalyst) attribute to conditionally import AppKit and use its APIs2.
https://www.swiftdevjournal.com/using-a-uikit-or-appkit-view-in-swiftui/

Comment: This repo nicely shows how to call AppKit: https://github.com/mhdhejazi/Catalyst-AppKit